# How to generate token and create a url to send to email

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to write a script for a student registration page, where a student enters his/her student id and if it exists then retrieve his/her email and generate a token and insert the token into the database and then send a registration url link with token and id to the student's email..how would i get that since i am a beginner in php and mysql.
where am i going wrong here?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
    session_start();
    include 'includes/connect.php';
    include 'includes/tokengenerator.php';
    if ($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit") {
        $stu_id = $_POST['stu_id'];
        $sql = "SELECT email FROM people WHERE stu_id = :stu_id";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':stu_id', $stu_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $email = $result['email'];
            //echo $email;
            //exit();
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
                $token = generateToken();
                //echo $token;
                $email = $result['email'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO students (token) VALUES ($token) WHERE email = :email";
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':token' => $token,
                ));
                $result1 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Please Contact principal for student ID';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use `update query` instead of `insert`

Comment: i did that as you suggested, but its throwing a syntax error saying WHERE email = ?'

Comment: how to create a url with token and id and send a mail using phpmailer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the wrong value in the query: `:token` vs `:email`.

You should actually have 2 placeholders and bind both values.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (token) VALUES (:token) WHERE email = :email";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
     ':token' => $token,
     ':email' => $email
));
```

And as noted correctly by @Saty, you cannot have a `WHERE` clause on an `INSERT` statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (token, email) VALUES (:token, :email)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
     ':token' => $token,
     ':email' => $email
));
```

Or you might need an `UPDATE` statement instead of an `INSERT`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE students SET token = :token WHERE email = :email";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
     ':token' => $token,
     ':email' => $email
));
```

Comment: i am able to get the token updated, thanks a ton, but how do i construct a URL using the token and id and send the url link to that email?